# How to get a value of XML

Tags: javascript, html, xml

I'm trying to get value of XML file and aplly use it in Java script code.
I've got simple code like this:

```
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open("GET","data/names.xml",false);
xmlhttp.send();
xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML;
var speed_multiplier=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("speed");
document.getElementById("console").innerHTML=speed_multiplier[0];
```

with XML structure like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <speed>5</speed>
</root>
```

but it displays `[object Element]`in html. What I have to change, so it would display value inside it, so I could use it later in js script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `getElementByTagName('speed')[0]` the result will be an element: the first of the elements with tag name `<speed>`.

What you need is the `textContent` of that element, so the correct code is:

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open("GET", "data/names.xml");
xmlhttp.send();
var xmlDoc = xmlhttp.responseXML,
    speed_multiplier = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("speed")[0].textContent;
// here is what you need ^^
// now speed_multiplier is "5"
document.getElementById("console").innerHTML = speed_multiplier;
```